# Creating a wizard process in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I'm new to backbone.js and having some trouble wrapping my head around an issue I'm having designing a "wizard" type process (a.k.a. a multi-step form).  This wizard should be able to handle different screen branching logic depending on the user's response to questions, store the responses to each screen as the user progresses, and at the end be able to serialize all the form responses (every step) into one large object (probably JSON).  The wizard questions will be changing from year to year, and I need to be able to support multiple similar wizards in existence at the same time.

I've got the basics down as far as creating the screens (using backbone-forms), but I'm now to the point where I want to save user input and I can't think of the best way to do it.  Most of the examples I've seen have one specific type of object (e.g. `Todo`) and you just create a collection of them (e.g. `TodoList`), but I've got a mixed bag of Backbone.Model definitions due to different screen types so it doesn't seem quite so simple.  Any pointers on how I should be instantiating my wizard and its contained screens, and recording user responses?

If it helps I can post a jsfiddle with my view code that so far only goes forwards and backwards screens (no user input response recording or screen branching).

```
var Wizard = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.set({
            pathTaken: [0]
        });
    },

    currentScreenID: function() {
        return _(this.get('pathTaken')).last();
    },

    currentScreen: function() {
        return this.screens[this.currentScreenID()];
    },

    isFirstScreen: function(screen) {
        return (_(this.screens).first() == this.currentScreen());
    },

    // This function should be overridden by wizards that have
    // multiple possible "finish" screens (depending on path taken)
    isLastScreen: function(screen) {
        return (_(this.screens).last() == this.currentScreen());
    },

    // This function should be overridden by non-trivial wizards
    // for complex path handling logic
    nextScreen: function() {
        // return immediately if on final screen
        if (this.isLastScreen(this.currentScreen())) return;
        // otherwise return the next screen in the list
        this.get('pathTaken').push(this.currentScreenID() + 1);
        return this.currentScreen();
    },

    prevScreen: function() {
        // return immediately if on first screen
        if (this.isFirstScreen(this.currentScreen())) return;
        // otherwise return the previous screen in the list
        prevScreenID = _(_(this.get('pathTaken')).pop()).last();
        return this.screens[prevScreenID];
    }
});

var ChocolateWizard = Wizard.extend({
    nextScreen: function() {
        //TODO: Implement this (calls super for now)
        //      Should go from screen 0 to 1 OR 2, depending on user response
        return Wizard.prototype.nextScreen.call(this);
    },
    screens: [
        // 0
        Backbone.Model.extend({
            title : "Chocolate quiz",
            schema: {
                name: 'Text',
                likesChocolate:  {
                    title: 'Do you like chocolate?',
                    type: 'Radio',
                    options: ['Yes', 'No']
                }
            }
        }),
        // 1
        Backbone.Model.extend({
            title : "I'm glad you like chocolate!",
            schema: {
                chocolateTypePreference:  {
                    title: 'Which type do you prefer?',
                    type: 'Radio',
                    options: [ 'Milk chocolate', 'Dark chocolate' ]
                }
            }
        }),
        //2
        Backbone.Model.extend({
            title : "So you don't like chocolate.",
            schema: {
                otherSweet:  {
                    title: 'What type of sweet do you prefer then?',
                    type: 'Text'
                }
            }
        })
    ]
});

wizard = new ChocolateWizard();

// I'd like to do something like wizard.screens.fetch here to get
// any saved responses, but wizard.screens is an array of model
// *definitions*, and I need to be working with *instances* in
// order to fetch
```

Edit: As requested, I would like to see a JSON return value for a wizard that has been saved to look something like this (as an end goal):

```
wizardResponse = {
    userID: 1,
    wizardType: "Chocolate",
    screenResponses: [
      { likesChocolate: "No"},
      {},
      { otherSweet: "Vanilla ice cream" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hello. Can you explain what you want to fetch? What does the response look like? Maybe you can give an example?
Btw, very nice question.

Comment: Hi there, the fetch would be for retrieving the user's previously-saved responses to the wizard questions (which means I'd also have to have a save method working for the model).  I would love to give you an example of what the response would look like, but I just can't seem to think through how to structure this app enough to give you that.  I need a bigger brain!

Comment: @user1248256 OK, thanks to your question I've thought about this a bit more and have edited the question to include what I would eventually like a saved wizard query to return in JSON (approximately). Perhaps I will have to create a new model or patch some of Backbone's sync or parse methods?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The big thing you need to do is make the workflow separate from the views themselves. That is, you should have an object that coordinates the work flow between the views, holds on to the data that was entered in to the views, and uses the results of the views (through events or other means) to figure out where to go next.

I've blogged about this in more detail, with a very simple example of a wizard-style interface, here:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/05/10/modeling-explicit-workflow-with-code-in-javascript-and-backbone-apps/

and here:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/05/15/workflow-in-backbone-apps-triggering-view-events-from-dom-events/

Here's the basic code from that first post, which shows the workflow object and how it coordinates the views:

```
orgChart = {

  addNewEmployee: function(){
    var that = this;

    var employeeDetail = this.getEmployeeDetail();
    employeeDetail.on("complete", function(employee){

      var managerSelector = that.selectManager(employee);
      managerSelector.on("save", function(employee){
        employee.save();
      });

    });
  },

  getEmployeeDetail: function(){
    var form = new EmployeeDetailForm();
    form.render();
    $("#wizard").html(form.el);
    return form;
  },

  selectManager: function(employee){
    var form = new SelectManagerForm({
      model: employee
    });
    form.render();
    $("#wizard").html(form.el);
    return form;
  }
}

// implementation details for EmployeeDetailForm go here

// implementation details for SelectManagerForm go here

// implementation details for Employee model go here
```

Comment: +1, thanks for the response. I've read the blog posts and I unfortunately don't think this will be a good fit for what I'm doing (assuming I understand it). The wizard I'm doing only exists to create a blob of data that will be used to automate filling out an existing very-large-and-not-well-structured PDF file that I'm tightly coupled to, so I can't tease out all the pieces into nice models; it's actually easier to just have an array of generic "screens" as I have to end up mapping back into the PDF structure anyway. Definitely finding it challenging to fit this into an MVC-like structure.

Comment: +1 for the time you spent in answering that... from an addicted backbone user :)

Comment: How would you put the back and forth logic for those views? I have problems to understand to extend the callbacks with a "previous/next" logic without having a lot of redundant code.

Answer (score 5):

I'm marking Derick's answer as accepted as it's cleaner than what I have, but it's not a solution I can use in my case as I have 50+ screens to deal with that I can't break into nice models - I have been given their content and simply have to replicate them.

Here's the hacky model code that I came up with which handles screen switching logic.  I'm sure I'll end up refactoring it a lot more as I continue working on it.

```
var Wizard = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.set({
            pathTaken: [0],
            // instantiate the screen definitions as screenResponses
            screenResponses: _(this.screens).map(function(s){ return new s; })
        });
    },

    currentScreenID: function() {
        return _(this.get('pathTaken')).last();
    },

    currentScreen: function() {
        return this.screens[this.currentScreenID()];
    },

    isFirstScreen: function(screen) {
        screen = screen || this.currentScreen();
        return (_(this.screens).first() === screen);
    },

    // This function should be overridden by wizards that have
    // multiple possible "finish" screens (depending on path taken)
    isLastScreen: function(screen) {
        screen = screen || this.currentScreen();
        return (_(this.screens).last() === screen);
    },

    // This function should be overridden by non-trivial wizards
    // for complex path handling logic
    nextScreenID: function(currentScreenID, currentScreen) {
        // default behavior is to return the next screen ID in the list
        return currentScreenID + 1;
    },

    nextScreen: function() {
        // return immediately if on final screen
        if (this.isLastScreen()) return;
        // otherwise get next screen id from nextScreenID function
        nsid = this.nextScreenID(this.currentScreenID(), this.currentScreen());
        if (nsid) {
            this.get('pathTaken').push(nsid);
            return nsid;
        }
    },

    prevScreen: function() {
        // return immediately if on first screen
        if (this.isFirstScreen()) return;
        // otherwise return the previous screen in the list
        prevScreenID = _(_(this.get('pathTaken')).pop()).last();
        return this.screens[prevScreenID];
    }

});

var ChocolateWizard = Wizard.extend({

    initialize: function(options) {
        Wizard.prototype.initialize.call(this); // super()

        this.set({
            wizardType: 'Chocolate',
        });
    },

    nextScreenID: function(csid, cs) {
        var resp = this.screenResponses(csid);
        this.nextScreenController.setState(csid.toString()); // have to manually change states
        if (resp.nextScreenID)
            // if screen defines a custom nextScreenID method, use it
            return resp.nextScreenID(resp, this.get('screenResponses'));
        else
            // otherwise return next screen number by default
            return csid + 1;
    },

    // convenience function
    screenResponses: function(i) {
        return this.get('screenResponses')[i];
    },

    screens: [
        // 0
        Backbone.Model.extend({
            title : "Chocolate quiz",
            schema: {
                name: 'Text',
                likesChocolate:  {
                    title: 'Do you like chocolate?',
                    type: 'Radio',
                    options: ['Yes', 'No']
                }
            },
            nextScreenID: function(thisResp, allResp) {
                if (thisResp.get('likesChocolate') === 'Yes')
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 2;
            }
        }),
        // 1
        Backbone.Model.extend({
            title : "I'm glad you like chocolate!",
            schema: {
                chocolateTypePreference:  {
                    title: 'Which type do you prefer?',
                    type: 'Radio',
                    options: [ 'Milk chocolate', 'Dark chocolate' ]
                }
            },
            nextScreenID: function(thisResp, allResp) {
                return 3; // skip screen 2
            }
        }),
        // 2
        Backbone.Model.extend({
            title : "So you don't like chocolate.",
            schema: {
                otherSweet:  {
                    title: 'What type of sweet do you prefer then?',
                    type: 'Text'
                }
            }
        }),
        // 3
        Backbone.Model.extend({
            title : "Finished - thanks for taking the quiz!"
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At [CloudMunch](https://github.com/cloudmunch/marionette-wizard), we had a similar need and built [Marionette-Wizard](https://github.com/cloudmunch/marionette-wizard).

w.r.t the explicit Q, in this wizard all the content is stored in localStorage and can be accessed as an object similar to the format you've specified.